# Disabling Add/Remove item animation of ListView "temporarily"

Tags: c#, uwp

How can I disable Add/Remove animation of a ListView "temporarily"?

I want to disable it when I navigate back to a page and restore the ScrollViewer position of a ListView on that page, since animation messes up the VerticalOffset if I set the ScrollViewer position during the Loaded event of the page.

After the page is loaded and scroll position is set, I want the animation to be enabled again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ListView will animate in the initial items once the control has loaded. So, you can just clear the item container transitions first then set it back once the control has loaded.

With a ListView named `listView`, in the constructor of your Page you can do this:

```
listView.ItemContainerTransitions = null;
listView.Loaded += (s, e) => listView.ClearValue(ItemsControl.ItemContainerTransitionsProperty);
```

You can bundle this up into an attached property or a behavior if you want to reuse it.